# Set directory of .gitlab-ci.yml via REST

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

Gitlab allows you to change the place it looks for the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

[image]

I want to change this location via REST in all projects of a gitlab group.

Although I browsed through the gitlab rest api description, I was not able to find the right endpoint.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [edit project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#edit-project) API. The parameter controlling this is the `ci_config_path`.

```sh
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your-token>" \
     --url 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<your-project-ID>' \
     --data "ci_config_path=path/to/ci-config.yml"
```

Comment: Do you have a good idea to do this for all projects in a group at once? Or do I need to read the list of all projects and then iterate over it?

Comment: Yeah, listing all projects and setting this for each would be the way. As a side note, for self-hosted customers, there is an administrative setting _similar_ to this called [required pipeline configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/continuous_integration.html#required-pipeline-configuration) set at the instance level. It's an easy way to make sure all pipelines include a central configuration with a single admin setting. Available in Premium until GitLab 15. After v15, it will be available for Ultimate customers only. @JFabianMeier